# Copyright transfer on death where copyright cannot be transferred?

Tags: copyright, france, inheritance, copyright-transfer

[The wikipedia page on Copyright transfer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_transfer_agreement) mentions that in "some countries, a transfer of copyright is not legally allowed, and only licensing is possible".

Does this also apply to the copyright after death (in such jurisdictions)? Do only the exploitation rights transfer onto the creator's heirs?

Comment: Which country? Laws differ.

Comment: @DaleM Do they? Can more (in this regard relevant/meaningful) distinctions, apart from the transferability, be made?

Comment: @DaleM Anyway, the Wikipedia page mentions France e.g. as a country where "moral rights last indefinitely", and it also happens to be one of those countries where (active) copyright transfer is not possible so just using France as an example would be totally OK as an answer.

Comment: I don't find the word "France" on that Wikipedia page.

Comment: @phoog Oops, I was probably looking at the wrong tab. I think I was looking at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright#Moral_rights

Comment: Ok, but France does seem to permit transfer of economic rights, so it's not "one of those countries where (active) copyright transfer is not possible."

Comment: @phoog Those aren't different things? From what I understand it there are rights innately bound to authorship, with the justification being that those are personal rights and thus non-transferable.

Comment: @phoog But now that I think about it, authorship itself cannot be transferred anywhere, it's always some rights which originally only the author has, such as the one to create copies and so it's called the *copy*-right… But is there then a difference between transferring someone copyright and giving someone an exclusive license (possibly with the promise to not make use of this right oneself)? I am confused.

Comment: Right.  Anywhere that recognizes so-called "moral rights" doesn't allow their transfer.  But "economic rights," including the right to exploit the work by making copies and selling them, are transferable, at least in the small number of copyright codes with which I am familiar.  The thing about France is that it has identified the right to withdraw the work from publication as a moral right that cannot be transferred.

Answer (score 2):

[French copyright law for posthumous works (a book)](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/15959/french-copyright-law-for-posthumous-works-a-book?rq=1) quotes the relevant bit of French law. This shows *why* transfer of copyright is impossible: the law states explicitly who owns the copyright. A contract cannot change this.

So, after the death of an author the heirs own the copyright, not because it was part of the estate, but because copyright law states so.

I don't see a specific restriction on just the transfer of economic rights, but the moral right to be acknowledged as the author (droit de paternité) is a moral right that by its very nature does not lend itself to transfer. The right to *stop* distribution however is transferred. Perpetual licenses are impossible.

So, with that in mind, the Stack Overflow terms ("any and all content [...] is perpetually and irrevocably licensed to Stack Overflow") are void in France.

Comment: License is not transfer, so the comment on the terms seems incorrect.

Comment: @phoog: License is indeed not transfer. But there are 3 parties here: the author, the heir and the licensee (i.e. Stack Overflow). The author-heir relation is at best transfer-like, not a true transfer. This relation is distinct from the licensor-licensee relation. Authors cannot bind their heirs to existing licenses.

Comment: "Authors cannot bind their heirs to existing licenses": why not?  I don't see anything saying that in the French copyright code.

Comment: "the law states explicitly who owns the copyright. A contract cannot change this": French copyright law certainly does contemplate the transfer of certain rights, obviously not including moral rights, by contract. 
An example is https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/codes/article_lc/LEGIARTI000006278922?dateVersion=14%2F01%2F2022&etatArticle=ABROGE_DIFF&etatArticle=VIGUEUR&etatTexte=ABROGE_DIFF&etatTexte=VIGUEUR&page=1&pageSize=10&query=Droit+d%27auteur+cession&searchField=ALL&searchType=ALL&tab_selection=code&typePagination=DEFAUT&typeRecherche=date

Comment: @phoog: It's a general principle in contract law that you cannot bind third parties. There's no need to restate that specifically for copyright licenses. The (presumed) heirs are not a party to the license between the original author and any licensee. On the death of the author, French copyright law gives the moral right to stop further publication to the heirs. That's a right granted directly to the heirs by copyright law.

Comment: there is also a principle known in English as "successor in interest," which includes heirs, and is perhaps an exception to the third-party rule.  The heirs aren't truly a third party.  If contracts didn't survive death, the world would look rather different.  Where is the right to stop publication identified as a moral right?

Comment: @phoog: The right to stop publication is a French moral right. _droit de retrait et de repentir_.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133207/discussion-between-phoog-and-msalters).

Comment: "are void in France" I would say "are void when French law applies", as I suspect that there are circumstances when French courts would apply non-French law pursuant to French choice of law rules (indeed, many of the key legal phrases in the choice of law field are French rather than the usual legal Latin).